# The long bootup time on a Windows 7 enterprise machine

Tags: windows-7, boot

The chkdsk program could not detect any  problems in my system . However it takes 6-10min to login to my windows 7 system after correctly entering the password. The "welcome" screen stays for 10 mins. To understand whats going on, i did a boot trace and I'm including the results in the attachments. Could an expert say what is causing the long bootup time? High res pics are [here](http://picasaweb.google.com/work.chandan/Win7_boot_slow?authkey=Gv1sRgCKSA9faFtImUKA)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to (auto)logon with other username? 
It can be possible your current user profile is damaged and winlogon boot phase (reading registry settings or so on) takes a lot of time...

Answer (score 0):

One or more services is timing out, and delaying everything else. This much is obvious from the pictures you've posted, but my eyes aren't as good as they used to be, even on this giant screen of mine.

Go into your Event Viewer, and look for services that take longer than usual to start. They'll usually start at set times from the bootup time, so look for three and five minute intervals. I'd be looking specifically for device drivers (including external storage, card readers, printers, etc.).

If that's showing nothing, I'd look at the way it's talking to the Active Directory. I presume you're running on a domain, being Windows 7 Enterprise? Maybe your domain controller is also causing one or more services to delay starting up as expected.

You could also try what's called a "clean boot", by disabling all services that don't have "Microsoft" in their name. Make sure you take note of what you're disabling, so that you can go through the (painful) process of enabling them one at a time and seeing if that affects the bootup time.

Comment: In domain environment the most common reason of long boot IMHO - misconfigured DNS settings or DNS server not available...

Comment: Good tip, Sergey.